# Abandoned Luggage Detection Dataset

Tags: deep-learning

I am working on a project for detecting abandoned luggage in train stations and airports. Is there some dataset that contains all kinds of bags and luggage? I searched a lot but I can't find any, and I would really appreciate if someone can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Talk to Amazon? They have lots of product shots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also looking for this kind of dataset and haven't found any.
So my solution was to build one from the images of the [COCO dataset](https://cocodataset.org/).

1. download the metadata and only save labelled images that have one of these 3 classes: `backpack`, `suitcase`, `handbag` (further I'd refer to them as just **bag**).
2. get rid of the pictures where the bag is carried by a person.  To do it, write a script that considers the bounding rects of all objects in the picture; if at least one bag in the picture has its bounding box intercepting with the bounding box of the object `person`, that's a good indicator that the bag is in person's hands/back/shoulder. The remaining bags may be considered abandoned.
3. save links to these images in a separate file and download them with CURL.

Note that this approach still requires manual clean-up after the images are downloaded, but that's the best you could come up with in absence of ready-to-use datasets.